# Unexpected request error: Error: unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: node.js

> I have trying to generate braintree client token
> but getting an error  // Unexpected request error: Error: unable to verify the first certificate
>
> this is my controller function...

const gateway = new braintree.BraintreeGateway({
environment: braintree.Environment.Sandbox,
merchantId: "",
publicKey: "",
privateKey: "",
});

```
    export const braintreeToken = async (req, res) => {
  await gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(501).send({ err });
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(response.clientToken);
      console.log(response.clientToken);
    }
  });
};
```

> is this error can be overcome by adding this line code ?
> NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
> But I dont know where add to this line of code ????

Comment: client token is being generated on other desktop, but not on my laptop what may cause of this ???